# Subshell (subprocess/child process) with its own $BASHPID not listed by `ps`

Tags: bash, process, subshell

I don't understand the following:

```
mkfifo p;
$ (>p ps -f | >>p echo $BASHPID) &
[1] 983527
$ cat p
983529
   PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
981815  165343  0 19:57 pts/27   00:00:00 bash
983527  981815  0 21:09 pts/27   00:00:00 bash    # <- child bash process `(...)`
983528  983527  0 21:09 pts/27   00:00:00 ps -f
983530  981815  0 21:09 pts/27   00:00:00 cat p
```

`(...) &` results in a child process with PID 983527. It is a bash process.

`ps -f` executes in a child process of `(...)` with PID 983528. It is the left hand-side component command of the pipeline `...|...`.

`echo $BASHPID` reports to be executing in a process with PID 983529. It ought to be the right hand-side component of the pipeline `...|...` and it ought to be listed as a bash process.

Is that last interpretation correct? And why can we not see that last process listed by the `ps -f` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>p ps -f | >>p echo $BASHPID` in `bash` starts two child processes at the same time, connected by a pipe. Both processes start with opening the `p` fifo in write-only mode (with the `O_APPEND` flag for the second one, but that has no effect on a pipe).

As that fifo has no reader yet, both `open()`s will hang there waiting for some process to open the fifo in read mode.

So at that point, you have those two processes in the starting blocks.

The left one still has to execute `ps` which means finding and loading the `/bin/ps` executable, loading the dynamic linker, loading and linking libraries, start reading `/proc`, etc, a lot of work. While all the right one has to do is expand `$BASHPID`, perform split+glob on it, invoke the `echo` builtin (just invoke an internal function) which just writes that expansion and exit.

Upon running `cat p`, as soon as `cat` opens the fifo, both processes above will be unblocked at the same time. The right (`echo`) one will likely have done its simple work and exited¹ long before `ps` has even finished loading, so `ps` will not find it in `/proc` which explains why you don't see it.

---

<sup>¹ and its death will have been acknowledged by its parent, otherwise the process would still show as a zombie</sup>

Comment: Oh I see... Indeed, running `(>&2 ps -f | >p echo $BASHPID) &` instead, which blocks only the right-hand side, allows the child bash process of the `echo` command to be listed in the output of `ps`. Thanks!